# Pinescriptv5: Is it possible to pull data from others indicator?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to do a strategy tester using my own stochastic indicator. But I also founds other's designed indicator useful and want to pull from their data source. Is there a function for this like in MQL4/5 using icustom?

e.g. after triggering my buy/sell condition, I wanted to pull other's supply and demand price level as my stop loss and take profit.

I have gone through input.source and ta. but can't find such function.

I have also tried copy and pasting the source code, but it doesn't work so well, as it stretch my chart with the stochastic all the way at the bottom of the bar chart.